# Passing JS function to C++ function emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten

I have function with such signature :

```
void generate_effect(const std::string& file_name, const std::string& out_dir) {
     ...
     ...
}
```

and binding such as:

```
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(main)
{
    function("generateEffect", &generate_effect);
}
```

so in JS i call it in such way:

```
const object = await Module()
object.generateEffect("file_name", "out_dir");
```

This works fine

But i need to make something like this:

```
object.generateEffect("file_name", "out_dir", function callback(success, msg) {
    if(success) ...
    else ...
});
```

The trouble is that i've tries different ways passing callback to C++ function, but they did not work for me, i've tried:

```
void generate_effect(const std::string& file_name, const std::string& out_dir, 
     emscripten::val callback) // works only when callback has no args

void generate_effect(const std::string& file_name, const std::string& out_dir,
     void(*callback)(bool, const char*)) // i must not use raw pointers
```

I've red about **optional_override** and i think my bindings should look like this:

```
function(                                                                                
    "generateEffect",                                                                   
    optional_override(                                                                    
        [](manager& this_, const val& error) {                                     
            this_.add_error_listener(                                                     
                 make_error_listener(                                                 
                    [error](const std::string& name, const std::string& message) {      
                        error(name, message);                                           
                    }));                                                                  
        }))
```

I have no idea how to pass callback with two params to C++ function in emscripten, i'll be glad for any help !

Comment: If you didnt get answer. try reddit cpp_questions

Comment: I don't think Embind currently supports binding types of closures.What you can do, however, is create a class, store the lambda as its property, and expose an `invoke()` method on that class that can be bound with Embind and exposed to JS. It's not ideal, but might give you a workaround for now. Please do raise a feature request on the Emscripten repo for a proper solution though!